# ng-click is not working in partial using ui-router

Tags: angularjs

I just starting with `AngularJS` and I have a routing issue with `ui-router`. Basically I have a partial that displays a button to sign in. The issue is that clicking on that button does not call the corresponding method in the controller.

The module definition:

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ['ui.state']);

myapp.config(function($stateProvider, $routeProvider) {

  $stateProvider.state('signin', {
        url : "/", // root route
        views : {
            "signinView" : {
                templateUrl : 'signin.html'
            }
        },
        controller: function($scope) {
            $scope.auth = function() { 
        console.log("clicked");
            };
        }
        //controller: 'LoginController'
    }).state('signedin', {
        views : {
            "signinView" : {
                templateUrl : 'partials/signedin.html'
            }
        }
    });

});
```

The `signin.html`:

```
<button class="btn" ng-click="auth()">Sign In</button>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xpgJmhs9UKQO7cNHSnoN?p=preview) thats shows the issue.

Comment: Where is the button in your plunker?

Comment: I fixed the plunker. The button is displayed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The controller definition should be inside the view definition.
Your code should look like this.

```
myapp.config(function($stateProvider, $routeProvider) {

  $stateProvider.state('signin', {
        url : "", // root route
        views : {
            "signinView" : {
                templateUrl : 'signin.html',
        controller: function($scope) {
                $scope.auth = function() { 
        alert("Clicked");
        console.log("clicked");
            };
        }
            }
        }
        //controller: 'LoginController'
    }).state('signedin', {
        views : {
            "signinView" : {
                templateUrl : 'partials/signedin.html'
            }
        }
    });
```

Here is the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fzlwOeXqF8b8HbnMb9bb?p=preview)

Answer (score 3):

I haven't used ui-router but by the quick look at the code I can see that you controller is defined incorrectly. It needs to reside inside the same object literal that defines your template:

```js
...
"signinView" : {
  templateUrl : 'signin.html',
  controller: function($scope) {
    $scope.auth = function() { 
      alert("Clicked");
      console.log("clicked");
    };
  }
}
...
```

The [ui-router docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#stateconfig) are clear about it.

[WORKING PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/FCVJFvhBRfIBCFnEqcNu?p=preview)